# stopping wpf animation fails with InvalidCastException

Tags: wpf, animation

I have some dice showing an int value and i am trying to animate them while waiting for a new random integer to show. I have an observable collection of DieViewModels and a datatemplate to visualize them. When i start rolling the dice (programmatically), i set the "IsRolling" property on the DieViewModels to true, which triggers the animation. The animation fastly switches the dice values. Up to here it works perfectly.

When i get the new values for the dice, i clear the collection and add the new DieViewModels. Then i fire the PropertyChangedEvent to tell the View that something has changed. And at this point i am getting an InvalidCastException.
Without the animation it works just fine. If i animate any other property but the (Binding) Value it works just fine.

I found a workaround, but i don't understand the problem. If i don't clear the oberservable collection, keep the old DieViewModels and set all properties to the new DieViewModels, it works. But the code for updating list elements from another list is quite ugly. And i still need the Dice.AddRange part to initialize the list, but have to make sure that it runs only once. ...except the new diceList contains more elements than the old one... i don't like this solution

DataTemplate:

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="DieTemplate" DataType="gameElements:DieViewModel">
     <Button>
         <Label x:Name="NumberLabel" 
                Content="{Binding Value}"/>
     </Button>
     <DataTemplate.Resources>
         <Storyboard x:Key="DieRollingAnimation">
             <Int32Animation Storyboard.TargetName="NumberLabel"
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Content"
                             From="1" To="6" Duration="0:0:0.6" 
                             RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
         </Storyboard>
     </DataTemplate.Resources>
     <DataTemplate.Triggers>
         <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsRolling}" Value="True">
             <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                 <BeginStoryboard
                     x:Name="beginAnimation"
                     Storyboard="{StaticResource DieRollingAnimation}" />
             </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
             <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                 <StopStoryboard
                     BeginStoryboardName="beginAnimation" />
             </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
         </DataTrigger>
     </DataTemplate.Triggers>
 </DataTemplate>
```

Method called to update the dice collection:

```
private void UpdateDice(IEnumerable<DieViewModel> newDice)
{
    Dice.Clear();
    Dice.AddRange(newDice);
    RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Dice));
}
```

I tried to stop the animation before reinitializing the list:

```
private void UpdateDice(IEnumerable<DieViewModel> newDice)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Dice.Count; i++)
    {
        Dice[i].IsRolling = false;
    }

    Dice.Clear();
    Dice.AddRange(newDice);
    RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Dice));
}
```

The animation stops, but the problem still occures, when i raise PropertyChanged.

I haven't written a for-loop in years and i think this is not 2020 c# style. So if there is no other solution for my problem could at least anybody tell me if there is a way to achive this using LINQ?

This should be at least a LINQ job:

```
 if (Dice.Count > 0 && Dice.Count == newDice.Count)
 {
     for (int i = 0; i < Dice.Count; i++)
     {
         Dice[i].IsRolling = false;
         Dice[i].Value = newDice[i].Value;
         // update some more properties
     }                
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must stop the `Storyboard` before clearing the collection by setting `IsRolling`to `false`. The `Storyboard` is still binding to the `IsRolling` property of the items.

The LINQ variant of the for-loop (requires reference to `System.ValueTuple`):

```
Dice.Take(Dice.Count)
  .Zip(newDice.Take(Dice.Count), (oldDice, newDice) => (oldDice, newDice)  
  .ToList()
  .ForEach(dicePair => 
    {
      dicePair.oldDice.IsRolling = false;
      dicePair.oldDice.Value = dicePair.newDice.Value;
    });
```

The for-loop is still valid *"2020 c# style"*. It performs far better in most scenarios.

Comment: sounds reasonable, but it does not work. The animation stops, but when i RaisePropertyChanged i am still getting an exception.

Comment: Can you please show the complete exception message? Generally if you are binding to a collection like `Dice` and you modify this collection, then this collection should be a `ObservableCollection` (or in general a collection that implements `INotifyCollctionChanged`). When adding/removing/moving items of a `ObservableCollection` the binding target e.g. `ItemsControl` will update itself automatically and show the changes. I highly recommend `ObservableCollection` which increases the performance as you you don't need to raise `PropertyChanged` for the collection property anymore.